# How to fix plymouth to it's default

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, video, plymouth

So today the new Ubuntu release came out. I uninstalled my Nvidia drivers, made the upgrade and then installed the latest Nvidia blob from Xorg edgers.

Before the upgrade, my boot and shutdown splash was correct after following this thread: [How to fix no splash screen in Ubuntu after nvidia proprietary driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472879/how-to-fix-no-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-after-nvidia-proprietary-driver-installati)

Now after the upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10, my grub conf is still the same, but [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth) is now acting strange for some reason.

Here are 2 demonstrative videos so you guys could see the problem:

- [Video of shutting Ubuntu down](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfrj73s4chh008y/20141024_011800.mp4?dl=0)
- [Video of booting Ubuntu up](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ja0nmfdz6qzcc01/20141024_011821.mp4?dl=0)

UPDATE: I am not sure why the videos don't play on the site it self, but they are downloadable too from the same link.

On the the first video, you can see that a lot of the logging that should happen behind the curtains, is for some reason displayed over my Plymouth splash theme. I don't think the regular desktop user should see this kind of stuff when shutting down their PC.

On the second video you can see that the Plymouth's splash screen comes up for a second then appears a black screen with some random Terminal text in the top, and then for a second you can see the Plymouth's loading dots in the middle in some very glitchy manner.

So what is up with this? Is this fixable and should I make a bug-report about this to Launchpad also?

EDIT: Also worth noting this quote from Plymouth's wiki:

> Note that on Ubuntu, Plymouth is considered to be the "owner" of the
>   console device (`/dev/console`) so no application should attempt to
>   modify terminal attributes for this device at boot or shutdown.

As I understand it, no other application should interfere with what is displayed by Plymouth.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tryed to reinstall the Plymouth from the drop shell, or enter in the terminal:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure Plymouth
```

and you can also type in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

it might work fine this way.

Comment: It tells me that: `E: Command line option --reconfigure is not understood` when I run the first command?

Comment: And I also tried the reinstall option, still having the same problem.

Comment: @Michael, did you mean "sudo dpkg-reconfigure plymouth" ?

Comment: @PJ Singh , tried it and it did not fix the problem also.